# Pydantic: Specify value as required yet input example value

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I am using Pydantic in FastAPI, to define in an OpenAPI doc.
Realised that to define a value as required, I need to keep the values empty, like below.

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: str
    price: float
    tax: float
```

However, I wanted to give an the JSON with example values, which I can create with the below syntax.

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str = "my name"
    description: str = "my description"
    price: float = 0.234
    tax: float = 0.20
```

But this will render them as not required in OpenAPI docs. Is there any way where I can specify them as required, and yet give an example value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on docs [Schema Extra - Example](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/):

You can declare extra `Config.schema_extra` for your `BaseModel` as such:

```py
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: str
    price: float
    tax: float

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "name": "my name",
                "description": "my description",
                "price": 0.234,
                "tax": 0.20
            }
        }
```

Or declare explicitly with `pydantic.Field`:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(..., example="my name")
    description: str = Field(..., example="my description")
    price: float = Field(..., example=0.234)
    tax: float = Field(..., example=0.20)
```